# How to know if java.util.concurrent Future Interface is still valid?

Tags: java, future

In my application I add a task to a "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" with the method "submit (Callable  task)". The method returns a "Future" whose result I evaluate in another thread. But this thread runs other code and it might take a while to execute "Future.get ()".

I have found that C ++ provides a "future :: valid" function to check if the value returned by "future :: get" is still valid. But Java provides neither a method nor an exception that indicates whether "Future.get ()" is no longer valid (in case the Garbage Collector has already removed the corresponding task from the "ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" queue).

What is recommended to do? Should I try to remove the rest of the tasks from the reading thread and make it just wait for "Future.get ()" as soon as possible?

Comment: Why would the GC remove a task from the queue? What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: @AndyTurner I assumed that the GC was in charge of deleting the non-repetitive  already executed tasks from the queue. I plan to put a lot of tasks indefinitely. So should I manually delete the tasks that have already run?

Answer (score 2):

Java is not C++. `Future.get()` is "valid" as long as you have a reference to said variable and won't get collected by the garbage collector.

Mind that `Future.get()` will block if the thread hasn't finished executing. If you need to check if the result is ready or not without blocking, `Future` provides the `.isDone()` method.

Comment: I assumed that the Garbage Collector would automatically dequeue the non-repetitive tasks already executed. But (I hope I understand you correctly) if I remove the "Future" reference returned by the task, will the GC remove the task from the queue? I need to put a lot of tasks indefinitely, so I have to release the queue somehow.

Comment: No, dereferencing a Future won't remove a task from the queue -- it will just make it impossible for you to get the result of the task.